# How do I show most viewed posts on a per-month basis?

Tags: wordpress, posts

For last month this query worked, now this 3 days (new month started), no posts at all:

```
<?php $current_year = date('Y'); ?>
<?php $current_month = date('m'); ?>

<?php endif;

arras_featured_loop( arras_get_option('featured1_display'),
apply_filters('arras_featured1_query', array(
    'list'              => $featured1_cat,
    'taxonomy'          => arras_get_option('featured1_tax'),
    'query'             => array( 'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'year' => $current_year,
    'monthnum' => $current_month,
    'category_name' => Music,
    'posts_per_page'    => $featured1_count,
    'exclude'           => $post_blacklist,
    'post_type'         => arras_get_option('featured1_posttype')
    )
) ) );
?>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This was not pissible.
But now I found way to do this with plugin Wordpres Popular Posts.

Its working alone in template with this code:

```
<?php
if (function_exists( 'wpp_get_mostpopular' )) {
  wpp_get_mostpopular('range=weekly&cat=276&order_by=views&limit=8');
}
?>
```

Now, what I need to do is to use this code up into this template down:

```
<?php endif;

arras_featured_loop( arras_get_option('featured1_display'), apply_filters('arras_featured1_query', array(
    'list'              => $featured1_cat,
    'taxonomy'          => arras_get_option('featured1_tax'),
    'query'             => array(
        'posts_per_page'    => $featured1_count,
        'exclude'           => $post_blacklist,
        'post_type'         => arras_get_option('featured1_posttype')
    )
) ) );
?>
```

I think I need to put it inside here:

```
'query'             => array(
```

Problem is I don't know to turn query from existing to one with arrows 'range=weekly' to 'range' => weekly didnt worked.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what it is supposed to do :)

Comment: Show 15 most viewed posts of current month. It worked last month, the time I coded it. Now, when new month came, no posts at all. It is using wp-postviews plugin, meta_key (post_views_count) from custom fields to display results.

Comment: Hmm, the query looks like it's limiting things to articles *authored* this month. Do you have written any new articles over the past 3 days?

Comment: I didn't wrote any posts this month. Now, I wrote one, and it is in query. Yes, you are right, this query use posts from current month. How do I fix it to use all time posts, and show most viewed current month, please, if you know?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the plugin supports that at all! Its description page gives no indication that tracking by month/week/etc. is possible. Not sure whether a plugin exists that can do this.

Comment: Correct. Plugin itself can't do that. I thought I can accomplish this by using custom fields value and month, but it's not so easy, or impossible.

Comment: Yeah, it's more difficult than that because you have to actually *count* the views by month, week, etc. I guess you could reset all counts at the beginning of every month but then you'd lose all the total counts, which is bad too

Comment: I found one plugin which can do this in widget: http://wordpress.org/plugins/popular-widget. Now just to realize how to use plugin affect on home page posts list.

Comment: I updated my question, hope so there is a way now.